# Angularjs module is not available

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have `script.js` file and I wrote this code:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', [])
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    myapp.controller('bikeController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("/Home/Angular").then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.words = ['It', 'is', 'what', 'it', 'is']
        });
    });
});
```

And in my index.cshtml file inside the head tag I put

```
<script src="~/scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/script.js"></script>
```

these references but i am getting the "Module 'myapp' is not available!" error.

Also I have tried to include `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>` but it did not work.

Which point I am missing? 
(Angularjs version: 1.5.8)

Comment: Have you added an HTML ng-app directive into your HTML body?

Comment: Yes I added it. When move my code in html page inside script tag it is working but it does not work inside the my `script.js` file

Answer (score 0):

You should change it like this:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myapp.controller('bikeController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("/Home/Angular").then(response) {
            $scope.words = ['It', 'is', 'what', 'it', 'is']
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have also tried to run it out of `angular.element(document).ready` function but it does not work.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: I found my mistake. I removed name of function `mySucces` inside .then and it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load angularjs and script.js at the end of the body like so-

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="bikeController">
    //your scopes here
  </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="~/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~script.js"></script>

</body>
```

And you do not need document ready either. Since you making an `$http` request, make sure to wrap the div that shows `$scope.words` in an `ng-if` block so the data loads in html after the request has been completed.

Hope that helps !